# How do I express the following in set builder notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I express the following in set builder notation?  I am struggling with these.  I have tried already different ways but can't accommodate for example a sequence where the difference increases.

$$\{3, 6, 11, 18, 27, 38, \ldots\} \\
\{\ldots, −\pi, −\pi/2, 0, \pi/2, \pi, \ldots\} \\
\{\ldots, 1/27, 1/9, 1/3, 1, 3, 9, 27, \ldots\}$$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: any answer given to this question is wrong, there are infinitely many answers for each one, just use Lagrange interpolation for the known values and the fact that the answer to this type of questions are not unique.

Comment: What? just because there a multiple ways does not mean it is wrong...

Comment: there are infinitely many answers that work for the given values and also give infinitely many different values for the values that were not given, these type of questions do not contain sufficient information for a meaningful answer, they are just feel good questions that have no real value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If the difference is linear, try to look solve for the coefficients where
$$a_n = an^2+bn+c$$

Also, perhaps subtracting $2$ from the original sequence can help you see something.

Comment: Thanks i can do the first 2, but still not the third

Comment: don't focus on addition and subtraction.

Comment: any answer given to this question is wrong, there are infinitely many answers for each one, just use Lagrange interpolation for the known values and the fact that the answer to this type of questions are not unique.

Comment: @Arjang I agree. I am just providing a possible candidate.